# Hide the video created on cvNamedWindow in openCV and display video only on Qt label

Tags: qt, opencv, user-interface

I was created a OpenCV console Application on VS2010, and now i was designed a nice GUI using Qt and put the output video/image on Qlabel , project is run fine. but my problem is when i run the program output video is display on both Qlabel and OpenCV GUI called cvNamedWindow/cvShowImage . but i don't want to display video on Opencv cvNamedWindow. when i remove the `cvNamedWindow` command then video is not display on both Qlabel and opencv gui window. Here is a same question that i want ask: http://answers.opencv.org/question/2914/video-on-label-opencv-qt-hide-cvnamedwindows/

Please help me.  Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order for us to help you, it would be helpful if you posted some code.

Answer (score 0):

try qApp->processEvents() after setpixmap and remove cvwaitkey , it's worked for me

(qApp is My QApplication app(argc, argv) )

Comment: Where possible try to explain why/how a certain technique works